# Offline storage recommendation

Tags: wallets

After purchasing from a site like coinbase I would like to transfer from their wallet, what are some recommended storage options for ethereum?

My final solution is a hardware option like the ledger nano S, but in the meantime?

Comment: The question is slightly confusing. If you purchased from Coinbase, the wallet is Coinbase's so you won't be storing the wallet anywhere. If you mean to say that you want to transfer the ether to a private wallet in your own hands, perhaps you could edit the question to make that more clear. I was a bit confused at first because you don't say you are explicitly intending to transfer the ether away from Coinbase, and if you're not, then you don't need to store anything anywhere.

Comment: Good point, Thomas.

Comment: I think other options mentioned in the duplicate question are enough to keep your Ether safe while you get a Ledger. If you're looking for offline storage options the Icebox solution mentioned in the question might be what you're looking for. Mist, Parity and MyEtherWallet also mentioned in the duplicate are able to create wallets offline.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime a usb stick will do. 
Nano S takes a while to ship currently...

Comment: That's what I was hearing about the Nano S, too.

Answer (score 0):

The [TREZOR](https://trezor.io/) hardware wallet supports storage of Ether; the web-based [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com/) knows how to integrate with that device ([blog post announcing that integration](https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-integration-with-myetherwallet-3e217a652e08)).